# Index of a numpy array within a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the index of a particular numpy array with in a sequence. For example, given:

```
import numpy as np

WHITE = np.array([255, 255, 255])
BLUE = np.array([0, 0, 255])
GRAY = np.array([192, 192, 192])
BLACK = np.array([0, 0, 0])
GREEN = np.array([0, 255, 0])
YELLOW = np.array([255, 255, 0])
COLORS = (WHITE, BLUE, GRAY, BLACK, GREEN)
```

I'd like to be able to ask for something like

```
print(COLORS.index(GRAY))
```

but this leads to the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I do have a workaround, but it feels overly acrobatic:

```
def index_of(x, sequence):
    eq = list((item == x).all() for item in sequence)
    return eq.index(True)

print(index_of(GRAY, COLORS))
```

Is there are more elegant/Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just use a `dict`? But essentially, no, since `index` uses `==` and `==` produces an array.

Comment: `next(i for (i, item) in enumerate(sequence) if (item == x).all())`
would be slightly more elegant I think, although it is not very pretty either

Comment: Although, there are several ways to make your approach more elegant. Starting by not using `list(<generator expression>)` and just using a list-comprehension. Or better yet, just use a for-loop and return early....

Comment: @tehforsch you should just use a for-loop in that case. Wayyyy more elegant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and then have a break-statement? thats fine too, whether that is more elegant is a matter of taste i would say

Comment: @tehforsch no, just `return` from your function. I would say creating a generator object to get a single item is decidedly *not* elegant. It will also be  slower.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga A generator object does (almost) exactly the same thing as a for loop - thats the point. That is why it is a bad idea to use lists here, that just uses up memory for no reason.

Comment: With small lists like this, memory use isn't a problem.  Use generators if it makes your code cleaner and easier to understand.  Otherwise don't make  a big deal about the differences.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree - it doesn't make a difference here at all, but I do think that it's a good habit to use generator expressions instead of lists whenever possible. It's not important though

Answer (score 2):

May be a matter of taste but in this case a for loop could be more readable:

```
def index_of(search_for, arrays):
    for i, array in enumerate(arrays):
        if np.array_equal(search_for, array):
            return i
    raise ValueError('{} not in sequence'.format(search_for))
```

`numpy` function `np.array_equal` allows for comparison of arrays of different sizes in case you'll need it (`(item == x).all()` will raise an exception for different array sizes)

Also raise a `ValueError` exception to mimic the `index` function of the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you index not by values, but by actual objects, you should be able to use `is`:

```
def index_of(color, seq):
    return next(i for i, x in enumerate(seq) if x is color)
```

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't that just going to return `color`, rather than the index where `color` appears?

Answer (score 0):

If `COLORS` was a list of lists, then the `index` works:

```
In [39]: C = [c.tolist() for c in COLORS]
In [40]: C
Out[40]: [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 255], [192, 192, 192], [0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]]
In [41]: C.index(GRAY.tolist())
Out[41]: 2
```

With array elements, the `index` does something like:

```
In [44]: [c==GRAY for c in COLORS]
Out[44]: 
[array([False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)]
```

Equality tests with array are done element by element, with the result being a boolean array.  But using a boolean array in a context that expects a simple scalar boolean, results in the (all-too-common) ambiguity error.  `all` can reduce those arrays to single values.

```
In [46]: [(c==GRAY).all() for c in COLORS]
Out[46]: [False, False, True, False, False]

In [47]: [(c==GRAY).all() for c in COLORS].index(True)
Out[47]: 2
In [48]: [(c==BLUE).all() for c in COLORS].index(True)
Out[48]: 1
```

If `COLORS` is turned into a 2d array, we can do test like:

```
In [49]: CA = np.array(COLORS)
In [50]: CA
Out[50]: 
array([[255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [192, 192, 192],
       [  0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0]])
In [51]: CA==GRAY
Out[51]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [52]: (CA==GRAY).all(axis=1)
Out[52]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```